# Access button content (which is an image) through code in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, button

I have a button that features a grid which in turn contains an image.

```
   <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" Margin="0,0,0,2.667" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image x:Name="img1" Source="Images/Numbers/1.png" Margin="-10,-3,-10,-5" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Grid>
    </Button>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to access the image holder through code without having to explicitly name it as I have above? If I had several buttons and could do it differently it might be easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can:

```
    var theImage = (Image)((Grid)btn1.Content).Children[0];
```

you have to make sure though that the button contains a `Grid` with an `Image` otherwise you get a cast or null pointer exception.

Comment: @James: glad to help, please mark as answered if that did it for you